# What single word could be used to describe city adventures?

Tags: game-design, ui-design

I am developing an urban racing simulator in a very "underground" stylized setting. It's name is **The Underground King** and you have the ability to either:

- A) Race in a 2d side view.
- B) Do something in the city.

Doing either of A or B will pass the day since it's assumed it takes all day to perform that action.
My issue is that while racing levels are caled Racing, the city action/adventure is called Event which is both too generic, and conflicts with my game engine's internal event systems.

I have tried to find a relevant replacement that is descriptive enough on what it is, whithout relying to medieval fantasy type tropes such as "Adventure" or cyberpunk's very own "Run".

What I could think of / narrow down are: **Buisness** or **Biz**, **Happening**, **Venture**, **Risk**, **Encounter**.
Here are some examples of the kind of things you can find:

- You accidentally bump into a drunk thug who wants to start a fight.
- A dog has something shiny and valuble looking in its bouth and wants to run away to bury it.
- A suspicious-looking woman dropped a package in a trash can.
- You get a tip about an abandoned but heavily locked garrage.
- A rich businessman wants to put a bet on your next race but wants a guarantee.
- While driving with your crew, you smell something burning (with random consequences):

  - Somebody is playing with matches.
  - The engine is burning.
  - Somebody tried to sabotage your car for the next race but it shortcircuited.
  - A rusted part finally started spinning again. The car has higher stats now.

I am looking for a single word term that can apply to any sort of event as written above which is generic enough to encompass anything you can potentially gain from, but specific enough to represent its something you can pursue or happen to you while you are present in the city.

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: There are only two hard problems in software development: Cache invalidation and naming things. My decision how to name this thing would depend on how exactly this part of the game is presented to the player.

Comment: @Philipp If it would be a boardgame, then Racing and "Event" would be cards of the same pile. Pins on the map have same visibility, as you can see. Any pin can generate extra pins (if you complete them). Naming things IN ENGLISH for a non native speaker is even more difficult, yap :D

Comment: "Venture" would work, perhaps simply "Approach". Sadly, this is opinion based. You might be interested in https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Urbex. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

- Wander
- Buzz
- Rumble
- Slack(ing)
- Errands

Answer (score 1):

- Life Event
- Daily Life
- Daily Experience
- Daily Happening (Last 2 have been mentioned, just added Daily to them)
- City Life
- City Event

Comment: just realized he asked for single word, but I still think these would work fine.